# What material is Ord's weapon made of?

Tags: marvel, x-men, composition

In Astonishing X-Men #5, Ord, an alien villain hailing from the Breakworld, claims the following:

[image]

> there is no substance on earth this blade cannot cut through.

Yet, Wolverine with his beta-adamantium claws is standing in the same room.  Is Ord bluffing, or is his disc-like weapon indeed made of a unique metallic material ?
 And would it be able to cut through Colossus's Osmium skin (who appears later on in the comic) ?

The [Marvel wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ord_%28SWORD%29_%28Earth-616%29) doesn't have more information, only Ord's quote.

Comment: Considering his short duration in the Marvel Universe (all of 5 issues), this may be a question without an answer. There isn't a lot of detail about Ord out there. I'm not finding anything more than what you've already stated.

Comment: Hm, yes, I'm afraid that might be the outcome. Still, I wanted to put the question out there, as it genuinely intrigued me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an unspecified alien metal from the planet Breakworld.

According to [this forum](http://atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?p=1003843) his bladed weapons can "hurt Colossus noticeably" (bottom of 1st post). Not exactly cannon, but as @SocioMatt pointed out, probably the best info available.

Answer (score 1):

He could have just been wrong.

The simplest explanation is that Ord may not have had adequate information to make that statement.

Any statement made by a character must be evaluated from THAT character's level of information.

Comic universes are worlds full of hyperbole. Unless the character has the informational resources to make a definitive statement, all it is is their opinion or hypothesis.